# AS3 Accessing a movieclip that is inside of another movie clip and a child

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I hope the title isn't too confusing. 
I know you are able to access a movieclip that is inside another movieclip, like I had done;

```
function allowResourceCollection():void {
    caveman.btn_CollectResources2.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, checkResourceCollection);
}
```

but I have now changed it so that inside of the movieclip **caveman** there is another movieclip **cavemanmenu** that is AS Linkage **btncavemanMenu** and inside of **cavemanmenu** is **btn_CollectResources2** so I tried the following;

```
function allowResourceCollection():void {
    caveman.cavemanmenu.btn_CollectResources2.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, checkResourceCollection);
}
```

and I get this error;

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.     at
>   stoneApp_new_fla::MainTimeline/allowResourceCollection()[stoneApp_new_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:104]

I'm so confused at what is going on. All I am trying to do is by clicking on **caveman**, **cavemanmenu** pops up and I am able to tap on **btn_CollectResources2** which is nested inside of **cavemanmenu**. Here is all the code in the section so you understand;

```
var myMovieClip:MovieClip = new btncavemanMenu();
//Caveman Menu
function allowTapCaveman():void {
    caveman.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, cavemanMenu);
}
function cancelTapCaveman():void {
    caveman.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, cavemanMenu);
}
function cavemanMenu(event:TouchEvent):void {
    addChild(myMovieClip);
    myMovieClip.x = caveman.x;
    myMovieClip.y = caveman.y;
    //myMovieClip.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, cavemanMenu);
    //caveman.gotoAndStop(2);
    //trace('2');
    if (caveman.currentFrame == 2){
        cancelTapCaveman();
        allowTapCavemanClose();
    }
}
function allowTapCavemanClose():void {
    caveman.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, cavemanMenuClose);
}
function cancelTapCavemanClose():void {
    caveman.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, cavemanMenuClose);
}
function cavemanMenuClose(event:TouchEvent):void {
    cancelTapCavemanClose();
    removeChild(myMovieClip);
    //caveman.gotoAndStop(1);
    allowTapCaveman();
    //trace('1');
}
function allowResourceCollection():void {
    caveman.btncavemanMenu.btn_CollectResources2.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, checkResourceCollection);
}
function cancelResourceCollection():void {
    caveman.btn_CollectResources2.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, checkResourceCollection);
}
function checkResourceCollection(event:TouchEvent):void {
    if(remaningActions >= 1){
        spawnWood();
        spawnFood();
        spawnStone();
        remaningActions -= 1;
        updateTextBox();
    }
    if(remaningActions <= 0){
        trace("not enough actions")
    }
}
```

As you can see, I used to have it so it would just change the frame in the movieclip **caveman** but because I need to create multiple **caveman** then I need to be able to have the menu pop up below them wherever they are and creating a child and bringing it in like that was the only way I could find. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event bubbles so the depth of the dispatching MovieClip does not matter. In fact, it is easier to let them be handled by `caveman`.

```
function allowResourceCollection():void {
  caveman.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, checkResourceCollection);
}
```

I highly recommend following naming conventions ...